# Multiple tabs in apple notes

Tags: notes.app, tabs

is there a way to open multiple notes in apple notes at the same time. It is the app I use for note taking at the moment (I keep changing but recently I've been using apple's default apps) and if I need to refer to another note, I need to access that note, exit it and go back to my original note. Is there a way to open tabs in them like in apple pages. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason the sidebar isn't sufficient for this task?

Comment: @Tetsujin the sidebar is used to go to another note right? then I would have to open that note, see/copy the stuff in there, and  go back to my original note and if the stuff I need is not together in the note, I have to repeat this as I can't copy and paste them at the same time and that's a real pain in the ass. I was wondering if I could open 2 notes at the same time

Comment: The sidebar acts exactly like tabs. If you want them open as separate windows, double-click in the sidebar.

Comment: Of course sidebar doesn't act like tabs... Notes in sidebar constantly change their position and when you switch between notes you will lose your cursor position within notes

Comment: I think @Tetsujin is assuming all of your notes are in the main folder at the same level. Then the contents basically do function somewhat like tabs. But alas many of us probably have much more complex organization with many levels of folders. The suggestion to double-click, though, is one I didn't know about. That itself will save me from (immediately anyway) finding a new note program.